# Concurrent access to MS Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access database/forms, controlled by VBA. Records can be deleted/modified and added. What is the best/natural way to share this database within only 3 desktop PCs? Would network share from one of the PCs would be sufficient and automatically taken care by MS Access? What additional actions in VBA I have to take care of? I'm mostly using `CurrentDb.Execute` to add/update and delete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Split the data and application into separate databases
2. Compile the application potion into an .mde (or equiv in 2007) to keep your users from messing with it, and put it on a share (or you can distribute it to each machine if you need performance).
3. Put the data db on a network share.

Ob. MS SQL Plug- better yet, convert the data db from MS Access into MS-SQL, and host it on a server and save your self some future pain, because with multiple users, MS Access is known to corrupt its own database from time to time. Even 2007.

Comment: For three users in a peer-to-peer networking setting, I see absolutely no benefit to upsizing. Jet/ACE should handle that load perfectly well. Corruption is simply not a significant issue with a properly deployed application that sees regular maintenance and backup in an environment that is stable (e.g., no WiFi, for instance).

Comment: Regular Maintenance, backups, and a stable environment. What you talking about Willis? I agree, corruption is less likely now than it was 10 years ago. However, F1 cars are less likely to burst in to flames now, but their drivers still wear Nomex suits. If your business can not continue to function without the data in the MS Access database, don't keep it there.